# how to remove certain amount of decimals in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If i have the following query

> select sum(8.9177 +   7.1950 + 5.1246) as total
>   from table1

Gives me `21.2373`

how do i round that figure to only be `21.2`.

I must always only have one decimal place, nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(8.9177 + 7.1950 + 5.1246),1) AS total 
FROM table1
```

Comment: I was concerned about `+ 5.1246,1))` it should be `+ 5.1246),1)`.

Comment: i tried this previously but it says "round is not a recognized built in function"

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

here are two solutions :

1. it will cast it it in decimal with 1 decimal point :

   select cast((sum(8.9177 + 7.1950 + 5.1246)) AS decimal(19,1)) from yourtable
2. it will round it upto 1 decimal point but output will remail in 4 decimal place

   select round(sum(8.9177 + 7.1950 + 5.1246),1) from yourtable

use 2nd option as it is simple and will not change the actual datatype.

Answer (score 1):

```
select CAST((sum(8.9177 + 7.1950 + 5.1246)) AS Decimal (10,1)) as total from tbl_name
```

Hope this helps.